# Is there a reliable method of passing microsecond time in a double?

Tags: c++, time, casting, double, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to work through a rather annoying issue, where I need report data with sub-millisecond precision time stamps.  The problem, is that the timestamp message field is a typedefed double.  I am only packing this message for a single receiving client, but this message is part of a standardized data service and I cannot modify the field any time soon.

I'm considering the consequences of copying two 32 bit values representing UTC seconds and microseconds to a double as shown below.  I don't really like it but it does seem to work.  However, what I can't figure out is why it does not work when I reverse the seconds and microseconds.  If I pack it the other way the second time is always right, but microsecond time varies by seemingly random values from (+/-) 1 - 500us

```
timeval tv;
gettimeofday(&tv, nullptr);
std::cout << " Original seconds: " << tv.tv_sec << "\n";
std::cout << " Original useconds: " << tv.tv_usec << "\n";
uint64_t ts = ((tv.tv_usec << 32) | tv.tv_sec);
double dts = (double)ts;
unsigned useconds = ((uint64_t)dts >> 32);
unsigned seconds = ((uint64_t)dts & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF);
std::cout << " Final seconds: " << seconds << "\n";
std::cout << " Final useconds: " << useconds << "\n";
std::cout << "diff: " << useconds - tv.tv_usec << "\n";
```

After looking at the IEEE-754, I'm even more confused.  It seems like if any bits would be misrepresented it would be the higher bits.

Anyway, I'd love to hear an explanation for this behavior and any advice on how accomplish this reliably.

Comment: Use the STL chrono library.

Comment: @Casey does the chrono library have functionality to pass microsecond time as a double?

Comment: Multiply all times by a million, and store whole numbers, integers, in a `double` value, expressed as a number of microseconds?

Comment: Converting int64 to double is a lossy transformation despite them being the same size. It can only accurately store roughly 50 binary digits, the rest are used for sign and exponent. So if first (largest) digit of int64 is 1, then the last 15 digits will be lost. You can read on numerical accuracy of floating point.

Comment: @mreff555 *"does the chrono library have functionality to pass microsecond time as a double?"* -- do you mean "time" as in [a duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) or as in [a time point](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point)?

Comment: `using FPMicroseconds = std::chrono::duration<double, std::micro>;` Microseconds as a double.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see why this happens, you have to consider what the value of `ts` will be prior to being converted into a `double`. In the code here, with

```
uint64_t ts = ((tv.tv_usec << 32) | tv.tv_sec);
```

the value of `ts` will be at most 1000000•2<sup>32</sup>. A 64-bit `double` uses a 53-bit mantissa to store the digits of the stored value. This means that for values less than 2<sup>53</sup>, the double will be accurate to the nearest integer, so no data will be lost upon conversion to `double`. For larger values, a `double` can only store 53 bits of precision, preventing some whole numbers from being represented.

When you switch the microseconds and seconds, the value of `ts` becomes about (1.6 billion)•2<sup>32</sup>, or about 2<sup>62</sup>. Because only 53 binary digits of precision are stored upon conversion to `double`, this number is rounded to the nearest 2<sup>9</sup>=512, causing the error you're seeing.

If I'm understanding correctly what you're trying to do, you need microsecond accuracy in your timestamps, so have you considered just calculating the total timestamp in microseconds, like this?

```
uint64_t ts = tv.tv_sec * 1000000 + tv.tv_usec;
```

This would guarantee microsecond precision, without getting anywhere close to the 2<sup>53</sup> limit of a `double` with perfect precision.

Comment: Great explanation.  I do like that Idea, It will be easier to explain how to cast it back to seconds as well.  At the time it didn't seem like it would matter which way that I did it, but now your way makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

An IEEE-754 double precision floating point number can represent 2<sup>64</sup> different values, but it's range is about 2.2*10<sup>-308</sup>-1.8*10<sup>308</sup>.  That's a range of more than 2<sup>64</sup>, so obviously it can't represent every distinct value in that range.  It gives up *precision* for range.

A simple `static_cast` to `double` (which is what your C-style cast will end up doing) is insufficient to pack bits of a `uint64_t` into a `double`.  That will convert the *numeric* value of the `uint64_t` to `double`, with all of the potential loss of precision that entails.

What you could do instead, is to actually copy the underlying bytes of the `uint64_t` into the storage of the `double`.  For example:

```
double dts = std::bit_cast<double>(ts);

// or, pre-C++17
double dts;
std::copy(
    reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&ts),
    reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&ts) + sizeof(uint64_t),
    &dts
);
```

When unpacking the value on the other side you can do the same thing in reverse.

Comment: note that the packing version is not guaranteed to survive being copied as a `double` , e.g. the FP registers might normalize number, or generate a trap on invalid representation

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of the question is that what is desired is a timer returning a `double` that returns system time with at least microsecond resolution. Below is code for this purpose that I have been using for more than twenty years now without issues.

It returns the system time in seconds, with slightly finer than microsecond resolution *at present*. Microsecond resolution requires 20 bits, and the count of seconds since January 1, 1970 presently stands at about 1.667 billion so it fits into 31 bits, for a total storage requirements of 51 bits. Since a `double` based on IEEE-754 `binary64` format has 52 *stored* significand bits this allows for comfortably storing the total count of microseconds since January 1, 1970 at this time and for several more decades to come.

However, if there is a requirement to keep the timestamp mechanism future proof for centuries, this approach is *not* suitable as it will break eventually (due to the limited number of bits available in a `double` to store a microsecond count) unless Unix-y platforms re-bias the starting point of system time keeping to a later date.

```c
#if defined(_WIN32)
#if !defined(WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN)
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif
#include <windows.h>
double second (void)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER t;
    static double oofreq;
    static int checkedForHighResTimer;
    static BOOL hasHighResTimer;

    if (!checkedForHighResTimer) {
        hasHighResTimer = QueryPerformanceFrequency (&t);
        oofreq = 1.0 / (double)t.QuadPart;
        checkedForHighResTimer = 1;
    }
    if (hasHighResTimer) {
        QueryPerformanceCounter (&t);
        return (double)t.QuadPart * oofreq;
    } else {
        return (double)GetTickCount() * 1.0e-3;
    }
}
#elif defined(__linux__) || defined(__APPLE__)
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
double second (void)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return (double)tv.tv_sec + (double)tv.tv_usec * 1.0e-6;
}
#else
#error unsupported platform
#endif
```